# $interval stops working in Angular after 2 repetitions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make Angular reload the page after 15 seconds showing a spinner but for some reason after two repetitions it will start ignoring the $interval function and start reloading the page the moment it changes (without waiting 15 seconds).
Any ideas?
Thanks!

```js
var getAll = function () {
  $http.get('/getAll')

  .success(function (data) {
      // something
  })

  .error(function (data) {
      // something else
  });  
}

getAll();

$interval(function () {
  usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');  
  
  $interval(function () {
    getAll();
    usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
  }, 2000);

}, 15000);
```

Comment: logic doesn't make a lot of sense .... internal interval will stop spinner every 2 seconds but spinner only starts every 15 seconds. Also every 15 seconds will create a new interval running every 2 seconds... going to have 4 internal intervals running every 2 seconds just in the first minute. Spinner should be stopped in the ajax callback

Comment: why do you need an interval thats suposed to repeat forever to do something once? You want to start the spinner, delay it 15 seconds, then stop the spinner and call getAll() right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for $interval, you need to set the "count", which is the number of times the $interval will repeat. In this case, it looks like you only want it to happen once.

Here we start the spinner. The interval then begins for a 15sec delay before calling `some_function()` which will stop the spinner and call getAll()

```
var some_function() {
   stop_spinner()
   getAll()
}

start_spinner()
$interval(some_function, 15000, 1);
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: I did just that a moment ago and it worked. I wasn't stopping the $interval. Thanks a lot!